# AWS ssm describe_parameters with ParameterFilter Option with Contains returns result but with Option BeginsWith does not return any data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am facing a strange issue on getting data from aws parameter-store. I am calling describe parameter to fetch the information about a parameter. Below is the Python Code for the same.

Parameter-Store : my-data.api_data

```
import boto3

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

response = ssm_client.describe_parameters(
    ParameterFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Option': 'BeginsWith',
            'Values': ['my-data']
        }
    ]
)
```

response = []
The response returned is empty list.
but if i change Option to Contains then i get the data.

```
import boto3

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

response = ssm_client.describe_parameters(
    ParameterFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Option': 'Contains',
            'Values': ['my-data']
        }
    ]
)
```

retuns information related to my-data.api_data

I am unable to get what might be the issue.
Please help.